# Sudoku grid with Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm writing Sudoku app in Flutter. Currently, the grid part.

Ideally, I want to achieve a grid like this:

[image: Sudoku Grid from Wikipedia]

This one has:

1. Squared grid and cells.
2. Clues that occupy full cell.
3. Cells that have some borders around them.
4. Some borders are bigger then others (at the edge of 3x3 squares).

But most importantly, grid should **be adaptive** (resize when there is not enough space).
All of my attempts (about 3 days of trying) failed because they were not adaptive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

took a crack at it - ended up using `flutter_layout_grid`

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_layout_grid/flutter_layout_grid.dart';

Widget sudokuGrid(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    // Aspect ratio will keep the cells as squares
    child: AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 1,
      child: LayoutGrid(
        // Set the cols and rows to be equal sizes
        columnSizes: List<TrackSize>.generate(9, (index) => 1.fr),
        rowSizes: List<TrackSize>.generate(9, (index) => 1.fr),
        children: [
          for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++)
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border(
                    // Conditionally set the border thickness
                    top: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: j > 0 && j % 3 == 0 ? 5 : 1),
                    right: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: i > 0 && i % 3 == 2 ? 5 : 1),
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: j < 8 && j % 3 == 2 ? 5 : 1),
                    left: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        width: i < 8 && i % 3 == 0 ? 5 : 1),
                  ),
                ),
                // Substitute text with text entry or
                // wrap with a gesture detector to make interactive
                child: Text(
                  "0",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    // Responsive text size
                    fontSize: min(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height) /
                        25,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It's good looking grid. But when width > height, it overflows :( [photo](https://imgur.com/SEfzBhd). my widget structure: Scaffold > SafeArea > Column > sudokuGrid. This happened with all of my previous grids. Maybe there is some way to fix this?

Comment: I was able to repeat that behavior and you can either remove the Column widget (easiest) or wrap the sudokuGrid widget in a Flexible widget (grid will no longer be centered, will have to add dynamic padding)